# Settings Drawer as fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I want to set SettingsDrawer as a Fragment in multiple activities (The settingsDrawer will display after click on specific button). The background of the settings drawer should be z current activity unfortunatly i tried to set fragment static (in activity xml) and also dynamicly. For first try i got inflating class fragment error and for dynamicly ive obtain a null pointer. Here is my dynamicly version:

**SettingsDrawer Class fragment**

```
public class SettingsDrawer extends Fragment{
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<SettingsDrawerItem> items;
    ListView listView;
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    RelativeLayout content;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_drawer_layout, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContext=getContext();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.settingsList);
        DrawListAdapter adapter = new DrawListAdapter(mContext, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        content = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.drawerPane);
        openAndCollapseDrawerList();

    }
    public  SettingsDrawer() {
        mContext=getContext();
        items = new ArrayList<>();}
public void openAndCollapseDrawerList()
    {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT))
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(content);

    else
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(content);
    }
```

**Settings Drawer layout**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/settingsList"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logoBox"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:background="#ffffffff" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Activity Part where I initialize fragment**

```
private void initSettingsDrawer() {
        Button settingsDrawerButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.settingsDrawer);
        settingsDrawerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                Class fragmentClass = null;
                fragmentClass = SettingsDrawer.class;
                try {
                    fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_main, fragment).commit();
            }
        });
    }
```

That gives me a nullPointer Exception.

Comment: null pointer exception comes on which line ? can u paste the crash log

Comment: it cant find the view of activity on line fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_main, fragment).commit();

Comment: your fragment is null i guess . can u paste your fragmentClass code?

Comment: the settingDrawer is the fragmentClass code EDIT I also want to mention that the activity_main is the view for whole activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code in your SettingsDrawer

```
static SettingsDrawer fragment;
static SettingsDrawer getInstance(){
if(fragment==null){
    return new SettingsDrawer();
}else{
    return fragment;
}
```

and in initSettingsDrawer :

```
fragment = SettingsDrawer.getInstance();
```

Comment: in SettingsDrawer getInstance() ive got warning that non-stativ field fragment cannot be referenced from static context, and function getInstance must be static if i want to use it in the activity

Comment: Yes it has to be static

Comment: I think i solve my problem but ive got another :/ Ive got DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY. error even if the layout width and height in DrawerLayout and activity_main are set as match_parent

Comment: make a custom layout instead of drawer layout like this and use this
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

Comment: Okay i solve it making RelativeLayout above the DrawerLayout and setting it to match parent. One more qustion: what if i want to add fragment to existing activity? I want to obtain smth like that http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/nexusae0_Screenshot_2013-09-12-12-36-52.png  i tried to write fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_main, fragment).commit(); but I still optain smth like that http://codetheory.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Screenshot_2015-02-01-19-30-28.png